# Add Jar into tomcat project

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a project which run in tomcat.
I have this error from tomcat.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.glxn.qrgen.javaase.QRCode.
I know that this error occur because I did not import my JAR file when I was building the WAR file but then I do not have the source code anymore which mean I cannot build a WAR file again.
Just wanna to know is there a way for me to put my JAR file into tomcat so the related function will call the JAR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy the jar straight into $CATALINA_HOME/lib and it should work.

Comment: hi @plog I have copied into D:\TomCat\lib which my tomcat is located and seem like my function did not know where to look for the JAR file

Comment: @DaveCruise it should work. The lib folder is where Tomcat reads classpath resources from. You could try redeploying your application to Tomcat to see if that helps it pick up the jar. If you still have no luck have a read here: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath